# SQL - sample n users for each month

Tags: sql, presto

I am currently working with a table that has attributes (`user_id`, `created_at`, ...). I would like to sample say 100 to 200 users that are created in each month since November last year. If I were to just select 100 users from one month, it would be easy because I can just do  this:

```
select * from TABLE where created_at >= 'xxxx' and created_at <= 'xxxx'
```

But I couldn't think of a clean way to do this for each month and then put the results together.  Is this possible to achieve this with SQL in any way? Thank you very much.

Comment: What rdbms and also what data type is created_at?

Comment: @SQLChao this is presto, and data_type for created_at is string like '2018-01-01'

Comment: Why would you store a date/time as a string?  You should fix your data model.

Comment: Are you really storing the dates as text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dates are really stored as strings `2018-01-01`, then you can take first 7 characters of the string to get the month.

Then, use `ROW_NUMBER` to partition by month and pick top 100 users for each month.

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    created_at
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            user_id,
            created_at,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY substr(created_at, 1, 7) ORDER BY user_id) AS rn
        FROM T
        WHERE created_at >= '2017-11-01'
    ) AS R
WHERE
    rn <= 100
;
```

`ORDER BY` defines which users to pick. The query above picks top 100 users by their ID, which is likely to be in the order they were created, so the query essentially picks first 100 users that were created each month.

If you want some random selection, then order by a function that returns a random number. This would look more like a "sample".

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    created_at
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            user_id,
            created_at,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY substr(created_at, 1, 7) ORDER BY random()) AS rn
        FROM T
        WHERE created_at >= '2017-11-01'
    ) AS R
WHERE
    rn <= 100
;
```

Comment: An awful way to store the dates, but given the date model, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog on using NTILE and TABLESAMPLE, which I think is exactly what you need here (Stratified Constant Proportion Sampling).

[data-sampling-in-presto](https://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2017/08/11/data-sampling-in-presto/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT user_id, created_at    -- and other columns
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y %m')
            ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 100 AND created_at >= '2017-11-01';
```

We use the MySQL function `DATE_FORMAT` to create a partition of each month and year, then we retain only 100 users from each partition.

Comment: In Prestodb, I would recommend `date_trunc(month, created_at)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming t-sql and created_at is a datetime. 
You could use ROW_NUMBER() (depending on the specific behaviour you're after you could use a few different rank/row type functions) to generate a row number for each year/month combination.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
Declare @rows int = 100,
    @date datetime = '2017-11-30'
SELECT *
FROM [YourTable] t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    from(
        Select user_id,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR, created_at), DATEPART(MONTH, created_at) ORDER BY created_at) as rn
        FROM [YourTable]
        WHERE created_at > @date
        ) as ds
    Where rn <= @rows
    and ds.user_id = t.user_id
    )
```

Edit: Written before the rdbms was specified, i'll leave it here in case someone else stumbles upon unless not appropriate.

Comment: `Assuming t-sql` ... this question is for Presto SQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: With no experience in presto it looks like it has a practically identical funciton for row_number (unless I'm looking in the wrong docs..) https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html

Comment: There is no `DATE_PART` function in Presto.